# How do I make an HTML element start at the same line but end with a newline?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a newline (`<br>`) after each `input` control. How do I do that in CSS?

I must add: I want the input control to *start on the same line* as the label or anything that precedes it but to have a newline at its end so that anything follows it starts on a separate line.

I understand this would have to do with the Flex box model but I am not quite acquainted with that yet.

```css
label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  display: / * what goes here? */
}
```

```html
<label for="theButton">Button</label>
<input name="theButton" type="button" value="Click me">
<label for="theTextBox">Button</label>
<input name="theTextBox" type="text">
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a display value?

Comment: you can easily achieve it by wrapping your form controls in separate div

Comment: Or with other css properties as shown in the answer here... There is no need to change the html structure per se, however, this cannot be accomplished by simply changing the single "what goes here" section in this snippet.

Comment: @Zuber Yes, I am aware. I should have mentioned. I want a CSS only thing. I am just feeling like dong it only in CSS. No other reasosn.

Answer (score 5):

Use a pseudoelement on the labels to force a line-break

```
label::before {
  content: "\A"; /* U+000A is the newline sequence */
  display: block;
}
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdvrOX)

This will place the label on a new line but it will keep the input in the same line of the previous label. You can also control the space between rows by setting an `height` on the pseudoelement

Comment: this is totally new for me. nice answer. keep it up :)

Comment: Wow! Thank you.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 this should still work when you add more input for a single label

Answer (score 1):

In case you **cannot/will not** change the markup set `display:block` with input and `float:left` with label.

```css
label {
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="theButton">Button</label>
<input name="theButton" type="button" value="Click me">
<label for="theTextBox">Button</label>
<input name="theTextBox" type="text">
```

By the way It's better to consider adjusting the HTML and use more elegant ways.

Comment: Thank you. A few minutes more.

Comment: I am afraid this falls into pieces when I add more controls with labels.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 that's why i said in bold if the html won't change :) ... There is no generic solution as it will always depend on your HTML/CSS